# Generating css (from scss) in different folders with webpack

Tags: css, sass, webpack

I have 3 scss files in my project and I want webpack to generate css's from them. The thing is I want each generated css to be in a different folder (within output folder). For example: for `one.scss, two.scss, three.scss` 
I want to create in output folder 3 folders: folderOne and in it `one.css`, folderTwo with `two.css` and folderThree with `three.css`. **extract-text-webpack-plugin** doesn't allow me to do this (it puts all generated css in same folder).

Comment: Look into this: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader. You could set up 3 different loaders that output to 3 different folders.

Comment: I did but I couldn't get sass-loader to generate a css.  I also looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211231/webpack-sass-loader-no-output-css-file and it says that the extract-text-webpack-plugin is used for creating css in output folder.